Feature enabling at member ports in dpdk
I have created a bonded port with two member ports.
But when I confiure the member port with some feature offloads It would be overwritten by rte_eth_dev_start().
How do I enable a feature at members port?
Note: If we are going to configure the feature at bond port, then we are getting error.
Offload feature at bond port configuration but getting error.
Configure Member ports but overwriiten by rte_eth_dev_start().

When the user opts to have a bonding port, they must not invoke ethdev APIs directly on subordinate ports comprising the bond. The only way to enable offloads is to do that on the bond port. When handling feature requests, the bonding driver makes sure that all subordinate ports support the features in question. In case of discrepancies it is supposed to throw an error and that is correct behaviour. Here is an excerpt from the driver's documentation:

To prevent inconsistency on how members process packets, once a device
is added to a bonding device, RSS and rte flow configurations should
be managed through the bonding device API, and not directly on the
member.

To make further assistance possible, consider to provide some extra bits of information:

vendor ID and device ID (as per lspci -vn) of each bond member;
which offloads (flag names) and via which APIs are requested;
string of EAL parameters used to launch the application;
OS distro/version + DPDK version.


Even I have all members ports with offload capability, I am not able to add feature through bond port configure. Vendor: Mellanox Connect X6, DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_TIMESTAMP in port_conf.rxmode.offloads via rte_eth_dev_configure(bond_portid, nbrxq, nbtxq, port_conf),

Eal params: --vdev 'net_bonding0,mode=0,member=port1_pci,member=port2_pci'.  DPDK Version: 22.03
